# GCP Cloud Functions no longer categorizes errors correctly with tracebacks

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I've been using Cloud Functions for over a year now and in the last month or so, there's been a change that's made it much more difficult to troubleshoot errors.

Previously, something as simple as the following would generate an **Error** in Logging with the offending line number and traceback (*KeyError: 'test'* here), but now Logging just shows *Function execution took X ms, finished with status: 'crash'* categorized under **Debug**.

```
def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    print(request_json)
    print(request_json['test'])
    return f'Hello World!'
```

Does anybody have any insights on what happened, and advice on how to proceed to troubleshoot Cloud Functions with crashes going forward please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm getting the impression that something is broken .... see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987350/is-finished-with-status-crash-normal-for-cloud-functions

Comment: Thanks @Kolban for pointing out the earlier thread. From logs of all my Cloud Functions, the first occurrence of a "crash" without traceback and categorized as "Debug" was on 2020-04-24T20:53:01.610 UTC, so this bug has been here for a month now.

Comment: GCP Support got back to me with the following update:
I've identified your issue as a known issue being fixed by the Cloud Functions product team. The symptoms of this issue are missing log statements in Python 3.7 functions, starting as of mid-April. This appears to match  the details you've provided, though please let me know if anything sounds off.

Comment: (continued): The fix for this issue has been implemented and the rollout has already begun. Rollouts can take a number of days based on the gradual rollout process used, and based on previous rollouts, I anticipate this being available in production by Friday this week. Please note that this ETA could be altered by a paused rollout or other unexpected delay, and we'll update you if we see anything change.

Comment: Still occurring for me.

Comment: Still happening.

Comment: Still happening...

Answer (score 1):

@chengineer provided the answer in the comment thread, this issue affected the Cloud Functions and it is currently under fix. The following updates will be posted on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215191.